# How to intergate multi single-sign-on like office365 in asp.net core app

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I have an asp.net core web app hosted in azure app service.

I've managed to setup aspnetcore middle-ware to use facebook, or microsoft or custom OpenID connect authentication provider.

But how do I integrate it with the 'login.microsoftonline.com' login page :
[image: screenshot]
resp.
[image: screenshol-multiple-accounts]

this page redirects to custom corporate SSO page based on entered email.

I expect that I will be able to invite people from multiple organizations to my app by using their corporate login.

Comment: You should check the docs, lots of great material on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/. What you are looking for is building a "multi-tenant" application that authenticates against Azure Active Directory.

Comment: If you formulate this as an answer, I will accept it. The word "multi-tenant" was the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is building a "multi-tenant" application that authenticates against Azure Active Directory.

A multi-tenant app is one where users can sign in from any Azure AD. (vs single-tenant apps that authenticate against one Azure AD tenant, single organisation)

You should check the docs, lots of great material on this.

Overview of multi-tenant apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview

Sample web application: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/.